# transition probability density of Follmer process

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

If Follmer diffusion process $\{X_t\}_{t \in [0,1]}$ satisfies the following SDE
$$dX_t= dB_t+\nabla \log P_{1-t}f(X_t)dt, \quad X_0=0$$
where $f=\frac{d\mu}{d\gamma}, \gamma(dx)=(2\pi)^{-\frac{n}{2}}e^{-\frac{|x|^2}{2}}dx$ and $B_t$ is a n-dimensional Brownian motion satisfied $B_0=0$.  If we denote heat semigroup $P_t$ given by
$$P_th(x)=\mathbb E[h(x+B_t)]$$
for any bounded continuous function $h$.

**My Question:** How to prove that the diffusion process $\{X_t\}_{t\in [0,1]}$ satisfies the transition probability density
$$p_{s,t}(x,y)=\tilde p_{s,t}(x,y)\frac{P_{1-t}f(y)}{P_{1-s}f(x)},$$
where $$\tilde p_{s,t}(x,y)=(2\pi(t-s))^{-\frac n 2} \exp\left(-\frac{|x-y|^2}{2(t-s)} \right).$$

Comment: What is $\mu$ here?

Comment: anyways, transition probabilities must satisfy Fokker-Planck equations. have you checked that?

Comment: $\mu$ is a target distribution, this comes from article, I don't check Kolmogorov's forward or backward equation.

Comment: perhaps you should then :)